# Find the minimum number of equipment required for a service period

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, modeling

I'm starting to learn operations research and trying to get my head around this problem that I have.

Problem statement: Find the minimum number of equipment needed to run a service schedule.

There are a set of machine types that need service during different times of the day for a period of 14 months (datetime data for each day of this period). Each machine requires a certain amount of different types of equipment for a set amount of time for the service.

Here's an example of what I mean:
Machine MC001 requires 2 multimeters for a time period of 5 minutes from 18:35 pm to 18:55 pm on 30/09/2023 and it takes 2 minutes to move it from one service station to the next so ideally we would need a total of 2 Multimeters: From 18:35 to 18:40 for MC001 then we can add two minutes (18:42) for the equipment to move to MC002 Machine and then it can be used at MC002 from anywhere between 18:42 to 19:00

I want to formulate the problem in terms of decision variables, objective function, and constraints to get the minimum number of equipment that would be required for the whole service schedule period.[image]

Comment: I'm unclear on how exactly the equipment counts change. What are you deciding? The sequence of the machine moving from one station to the next?

Comment: I am not sure if its indeed optimization/OR problem. Because such problems will require decision variables (continuous, integer, binary) with bounds. Constraints will also be bounds mostly ($ \le , \ge, \lt, \gt$). If all are relations with equal sign then perhaps best would be to use some heuristic or shopfloor planning s/w or even MS Project.

Comment: @Reinderien The equipment count changes based on the machine type. Each machine needs a specified number of equipment example Machine:MC001 will always need 2 "Multimeters" and 1 "work glove". There is no sequence of the machine moving from one station to the next rather the equipment would be moved from one machine to another, for example, there is a standard time of 2minute to move "Multimeter" from the MC001 machine to another machine.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Sutanu. What would be the problem if decision variables are with bounds? If we have to go through the OR approach can you give me an example of how the decision variables, objective function and constraints would look like? Don't have to be very brief just a basic understanding would help.  thanks

Comment: I still don't understand what you're _deciding_. What do you want the optimizer to tell you?

Comment: How is the "minimum amount of equipment" not just two multimeters and two pairs of gloves? Providing a worked example would help.

Comment: @Reinderien I'll try to simplify it,  let's consider the case where we need to find the minimum multimeters that would be required over the period in the screenshot. We can use 2 multimeters for a time of 5 minutes from 18:35 to 18:55 for MC001 and then we would need 2 from 18:40 to 19:00 for MC002. For this scenario, we would need a total of 2 Multimeters: From 18:35 to 18:40 for MC001 then we can add two minutes (18:42) for the equipment to move to MC002 Machine and then it can be used at MC002 from anywhere between 18:42 to 19:00. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Reinderien, @Sutanu I've updated the problem statement to be more clear and precise. Thanks for your time on it.

Comment: This has a strong touch of a *vehicle routing problem*.. So basically  partitioning (how many vehicles / tools / partitions) of a travelling salesman problem (arc = movement + embedded service time) with time-windows (service time-windows). Equipment cardinality needs some thought though. Maybe node-duplication tricks. or-tools routing-solver is a extremely generic and powerful solver for this kind of stuff.

Comment: If a machine asks for more than one piece of the same equipment, must they run service at the same time, or e.g. can one multimeter service the machine at a different time in the maintenance window than the second multimeter?

Comment: @Asheesh,  as the problem, the maintenance models, is categorized on the stochastic era, one of the best approaches is based on discrete event simulation to estimate what's really happened on the planning horizon towards probability distribution of the model events like, mean duration of the occurred failures, the determined service level, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add decision variables for:

- The actual start time of machine service within each window, continuous
- The actual start time of machine service for a given piece of equipment, continuous
- The actual duration of machine service for a given piece of equipment, continuous
- Binary assignment variables: for each piece of equipment, is it assigned to a given machine service window?
- The maximum value of the assignment variable per piece of equipment group, i.e. "is this piece of equipment used"; continuous

Constraints:

- If assigned, the start time and duration of the equipment service must be equal to the start time and duration of the machine
- The 'used' variable must be at least the value of each 'assigned' variable
- Each machine must have a fixed value for the amount of assigned equipment
- The difference between the stop time of the equipment service and the start time of the next equipment service must be at least 0, or at least the travel time if assigned

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import pandas as pd
import pulp

df = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.Index(name='MachineName', data=('MC001', 'MC002')),
    data={
        'ServiceTimeStart': [datetime(2023, 9, 30, 18, 35), datetime(2023, 9, 30, 18, 37)],
        # 'ServiceTimeEnd':   [datetime(2023, 9, 30, 18, 40), datetime(2023, 9, 30, 18, 45)],  # would require all 4
        'ServiceTimeEnd':   [datetime(2023, 9, 30, 18, 55), datetime(2023, 9, 30, 19,  0)],
        'EquipName':        ['Multimeter', 'Multimeter'],
        'EquipServiceTime': [timedelta(minutes=5), timedelta(minutes=7)],
        'EquipRequired':    [2, 2],
        'EquipMoveTime':    [timedelta(minutes=2), timedelta(minutes=2)],
    },
)

first_time = df.ServiceTimeStart.min()
last_time = df.ServiceTimeEnd.max()
one_minute = timedelta(minutes=1)
max_time = (last_time - first_time)/one_minute
max_dur = df.EquipServiceTime.max()/one_minute

'''
one piece of equipment moves from machine to machine, with a fixed move time between them.
machines have fixed windows of time in which they can receive maintenance.
equipment maintenance time is given to be smaller than or equal to machine maintenance window time.

we assume that EquipServiceTime indicates the time for one equipment type and simultaneous use of
all instances of that piece of equipment at the same time.
'''

prob = pulp.LpProblem(name='machine_maintenance', sense=pulp.LpMinimize)

# in the worst case, every machine needs a dedicated equipment set;
# i.e. the amount of equipment is at most the sum of all EquipRequired
max_equip_required = df.groupby('EquipName').EquipRequired.sum()
equip_idx = max_equip_required.apply(range).explode()
equipment = pd.DataFrame({
    'EquipIdx': equip_idx,
    'EquipID': equip_idx.index + '_' + equip_idx.astype(str),
})


def make_machine_vars(row: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    # per machine and equipment type, we need to decide when - within
    # the maintenance window - the maintenance actually happens
    startoff = pulp.LpVariable(
        name=f'startoff_{row.name}_{row.EquipName}',
        cat=pulp.LpContinuous,
        lowBound=(
            row.ServiceTimeStart - first_time
        )/one_minute,
        upBound=(
            row.ServiceTimeEnd - first_time - row.EquipServiceTime
        )/one_minute,
    )
    return pd.Series(index=['StartOff'], data=[startoff])


df = pd.concat((df, df.apply(make_machine_vars, axis=1)), axis=1)


def make_combos(row: pd.Series):
    suffix = f'_{row.MachineName}_{row.EquipID}'

    # is this equipment assigned to this machine service?
    assign = pulp.LpVariable(name='assign' + suffix, cat=pulp.LpBinary)

    # the start and duration time for this equipment to service this machine
    startoff = pulp.LpVariable(
        name='startoff' + suffix, cat=pulp.LpContinuous,
        lowBound=0,
        upBound=max_time)
    duration = pulp.LpVariable(
        name='duration' + suffix, cat=pulp.LpContinuous,
        lowBound=0,
        upBound=max_dur)

    # if assigned, then the equipment start offset and duration must equal that of the machine
    start_error = startoff - row.StartOff
    dur_error = duration - row.EquipServiceTime/one_minute
    start_tol = 2*max_time*(1 - assign)
    dur_tol = 2*max_dur*(1 - assign)

    prob.addConstraint(name='startlo' + suffix, constraint=start_error <= start_tol)
    prob.addConstraint(name='starthi' + suffix, constraint=-start_error <= start_tol)
    prob.addConstraint(name='durlo' + suffix, constraint=dur_error <= dur_tol)
    prob.addConstraint(name='durhi' + suffix, constraint=-dur_error <= dur_tol)

    return pd.Series(
        index=['Assign', 'EquipStartOff', 'EquipDur'],
        data=[assign, startoff, duration])


# per machine and equipment instance
combos = pd.merge(
    left=df.reset_index(), right=equipment,
    left_on='EquipName', right_on='EquipName')
combos = pd.concat(
    (combos, combos.apply(make_combos, axis=1)),
    axis=1,
).set_index(['MachineName', 'EquipName', 'EquipIdx'])


def make_used(group: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.Series:
    # for each equipment instance: is it used at least once?
    used = pulp.LpVariable(
        name=f'used_{group.name}',
        cat=pulp.LpContinuous,
        lowBound=0,
    )

    # if any assign = 1, then used = 1
    for (machine_name, equip_name, equip_idx), row in group.iterrows():
        prob.addConstraint(
            name=f'usedmax_{machine_name}_{equip_name}_{equip_idx}',
            constraint=used >= row.Assign,
        )

    return pd.Series(index=['Used'], data=[used])


# the objective is to minimize the amount of used equipment
equipment['Used'] = (
    combos.groupby('EquipID')
    .apply(make_used)
    .set_index(equipment.index)
    .Used
)
prob.objective = equipment.Used.sum()

# for each machine service period, it has an enforced amount of equipment used
for (machine_name, equip_name), group in combos.groupby(level=['MachineName', 'EquipName']):
    prob.addConstraint(
        name=f'nequip_{machine_name}_{equip_name}',
        constraint=group.Assign.sum() == group.iloc[0,:].EquipRequired,
    )

# For every equipment instance,
for equip_id, equip_group in combos.groupby('EquipID'):
    # For every pair of chronologically consecutive machine service periods,
    machine_groups = tuple(equip_group.groupby(level='MachineName'))
    for (machine0_name, machine0), (machine1_name, machine1) in zip(
        machine_groups[:-1],
        machine_groups[1:],
    ):
        machine0 = machine0.iloc[0, :]
        machine1 = machine1.iloc[0, :]
        suffix = f'_{machine0_name}_{machine1_name}_{equip_id}'

        # the new start must be after the old stop, plus the move time if assigned
        slack = machine1.EquipStartOff - (machine0.EquipStartOff + machine0.EquipDur)
        min_pause = machine0.EquipMoveTime/one_minute * machine0.Assign
        prob.addConstraint(name='chrono' + suffix, constraint=slack >= min_pause)

print(prob)
prob.solve()

assert prob.status == pulp.LpStatusOptimal

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
print(f'{prob.objective.value()} pieces of equipment used')
print()

equipment['Used'] = equipment.Used.apply(pulp.LpVariable.value)
print(equipment)
print()

df['StartOff'] = first_time + df.StartOff.apply(pulp.LpVariable.value)*one_minute
print(df)
print()

combos[['StartOff', 'Assign', 'EquipStartOff', 'EquipDur']] = combos[[
    'StartOff', 'Assign', 'EquipStartOff', 'EquipDur',
]].applymap(pulp.LpVariable.value)
combos.EquipStartOff = first_time + combos.EquipStartOff*one_minute
combos.EquipDur *= one_minute
print(combos[['Assign', 'EquipStartOff', 'EquipDur']])
print()
```

This run is shown for the more difficult version where all four multimeters needs to be used:

```
machine_maintenance:
MINIMIZE
1*used_Multimeter_0 + 1*used_Multimeter_1 + 1*used_Multimeter_2 + 1*used_Multimeter_3 + 0
SUBJECT TO
startlo_MC001_Multimeter_0: 20 assign_MC001_Multimeter_0
 - startoff_MC001_Multimeter + startoff_MC001_Multimeter_0 <= 20

starthi_MC001_Multimeter_0: 20 assign_MC001_Multimeter_0
 + startoff_MC001_Multimeter - startoff_MC001_Multimeter_0 <= 20

durlo_MC001_Multimeter_0: 14 assign_MC001_Multimeter_0
 + duration_MC001_Multimeter_0 <= 19

durhi_MC001_Multimeter_0: 14 assign_MC001_Multimeter_0
 - duration_MC001_Multimeter_0 <= 9

...

usedmax_MC001_Multimeter_0: - assign_MC001_Multimeter_0 + used_Multimeter_0
 >= 0

usedmax_MC002_Multimeter_0: - assign_MC002_Multimeter_0 + used_Multimeter_0
 >= 0

...

nequip_MC001_Multimeter: assign_MC001_Multimeter_0 + assign_MC001_Multimeter_1
 + assign_MC001_Multimeter_2 + assign_MC001_Multimeter_3 = 2

nequip_MC002_Multimeter: assign_MC002_Multimeter_0 + assign_MC002_Multimeter_1
 + assign_MC002_Multimeter_2 + assign_MC002_Multimeter_3 = 2

chrono_MC001_MC002_Multimeter_0: - 2 assign_MC001_Multimeter_0
 - duration_MC001_Multimeter_0 - startoff_MC001_Multimeter_0
 + startoff_MC002_Multimeter_0 >= 0

chrono_MC001_MC002_Multimeter_1: - 2 assign_MC001_Multimeter_1
 - duration_MC001_Multimeter_1 - startoff_MC001_Multimeter_1
 + startoff_MC002_Multimeter_1 >= 0

...

VARIABLES
0 <= assign_MC001_Multimeter_0 <= 1 Integer
0 <= assign_MC001_Multimeter_1 <= 1 Integer
0 <= assign_MC001_Multimeter_2 <= 1 Integer
0 <= assign_MC001_Multimeter_3 <= 1 Integer
0 <= assign_MC002_Multimeter_0 <= 1 Integer
0 <= assign_MC002_Multimeter_1 <= 1 Integer
0 <= assign_MC002_Multimeter_2 <= 1 Integer
0 <= assign_MC002_Multimeter_3 <= 1 Integer
duration_MC001_Multimeter_0 <= 7 Continuous
duration_MC001_Multimeter_1 <= 7 Continuous
duration_MC001_Multimeter_2 <= 7 Continuous
duration_MC001_Multimeter_3 <= 7 Continuous
duration_MC002_Multimeter_0 <= 7 Continuous
duration_MC002_Multimeter_1 <= 7 Continuous
duration_MC002_Multimeter_2 <= 7 Continuous
duration_MC002_Multimeter_3 <= 7 Continuous
startoff_MC001_Multimeter = 0 Continuous
startoff_MC001_Multimeter_0 <= 10 Continuous
startoff_MC001_Multimeter_1 <= 10 Continuous
startoff_MC001_Multimeter_2 <= 10 Continuous
startoff_MC001_Multimeter_3 <= 10 Continuous
2 <= startoff_MC002_Multimeter <= 3 Continuous
startoff_MC002_Multimeter_0 <= 10 Continuous
startoff_MC002_Multimeter_1 <= 10 Continuous
startoff_MC002_Multimeter_2 <= 10 Continuous
startoff_MC002_Multimeter_3 <= 10 Continuous
used_Multimeter_0 Continuous
used_Multimeter_1 Continuous
used_Multimeter_2 Continuous
used_Multimeter_3 Continuous

Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver 
Version: 2.10.3 
Build Date: Dec 15 2019 

At line 2 NAME          MODEL
At line 3 ROWS
At line 51 COLUMNS
At line 192 RHS
At line 239 BOUNDS
At line 267 ENDATA
Problem MODEL has 46 rows, 30 columns and 120 elements
Coin0008I MODEL read with 0 errors
Option for timeMode changed from cpu to elapsed
Continuous objective value is 2 - 0.00 seconds
Cgl0003I 0 fixed, 0 tightened bounds, 8 strengthened rows, 0 substitutions
Cgl0003I 0 fixed, 0 tightened bounds, 8 strengthened rows, 0 substitutions
Cgl0004I processed model has 30 rows, 21 columns (8 integer (8 of which binary)) and 91 elements
Cutoff increment increased from 1e-05 to 0.9999
Cbc0038I Initial state - 8 integers unsatisfied sum - 3.60216
Cbc0038I Pass   1: suminf.    2.49432 (7) obj. 2.75284 iterations 5
Cbc0038I Pass   2: suminf.    1.61364 (4) obj. 3.19318 iterations 8
Cbc0038I Pass   3: suminf.    0.00000 (0) obj. 4 iterations 2
Cbc0038I Solution found of 4
Cbc0038I Relaxing continuous gives 4
Cbc0038I Before mini branch and bound, 0 integers at bound fixed and 1 continuous
Cbc0038I Full problem 30 rows 21 columns, reduced to 30 rows 20 columns
Cbc0038I Mini branch and bound did not improve solution (0.03 seconds)
Cbc0038I Round again with cutoff of 2.90009
Cbc0038I Pass   4: suminf.    2.49432 (7) obj. 2.75284 iterations 0
...

Result - Optimal solution found

Objective value:                4.00000000
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               0
Time (CPU seconds):             0.05
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.05

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.06   (Wallclock seconds):       0.06

4.0 pieces of equipment used

           EquipIdx       EquipID  Used
EquipName                              
Multimeter        0  Multimeter_0   1.0
Multimeter        1  Multimeter_1   1.0
Multimeter        2  Multimeter_2   1.0
Multimeter        3  Multimeter_3   1.0

               ServiceTimeStart      ServiceTimeEnd   EquipName EquipServiceTime  EquipRequired   EquipMoveTime            StartOff
MachineName                                                                                                                        
MC001       2023-09-30 18:35:00 2023-09-30 18:40:00  Multimeter  0 days 00:05:00              2 0 days 00:02:00 2023-09-30 18:35:00
MC002       2023-09-30 18:37:00 2023-09-30 18:45:00  Multimeter  0 days 00:07:00              2 0 days 00:02:00 2023-09-30 18:37:00

                                 Assign       EquipStartOff        EquipDur
MachineName EquipName  EquipIdx                                            
MC001       Multimeter 0            1.0 2023-09-30 18:35:00 0 days 00:05:00
                       1            0.0 2023-09-30 18:35:00 0 days 00:00:00
                       2            0.0 2023-09-30 18:35:00 0 days 00:00:00
                       3            1.0 2023-09-30 18:35:00 0 days 00:05:00
MC002       Multimeter 0            0.0 2023-09-30 18:45:00 0 days 00:00:00
                       1            1.0 2023-09-30 18:37:00 0 days 00:07:00
                       2            1.0 2023-09-30 18:37:00 0 days 00:07:00
                       3            0.0 2023-09-30 18:45:00 0 days 00:00:00
```

You ask:

> explain the code underneath the comment `# if assigned, then the equipment start offset and duration must equal that of the machine`.

This model has an offset and duration within the service window of the machine, and then a model and offset for every single equipment instance that might be assigned to that machine. If it is assigned, then the machine variables need to equal the equipment variables. This equality is enforced conditionally using a [big M constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_M_method).

> I can't make out why we need to double the max_time: 2*max_time*(1 - assign) if there is no offset?

It's not if there's no offset; it's if there's no *assignment*. We double the maximum time to calculate a "big M": a coefficient sufficiently large enough that it can be guaranteed never smaller than the times with which it's compared.

> how the logic for start_error = startoff - row.StartOff works?

In this context, `startoff` is the equipment-specific start time variable and `row.StartOff` is the machine start time variable. This defines the difference between the two. If the equipment is assigned, that difference is forced to 0; otherwise it's left unconstrained.

Comment: Much thanks for the answer @Reinderien, I'm going through the code that you have share (lot to learn and understand). can you please explain the code underneath the comment "# if assigned, then the equipment start offset and duration must equal that of the machine". I can't make out why we need to double the max_time: 2*max_time*(1 - assign) if there is no offset? Also how the logic for start_error = startoff - row.StartOff works?

Comment: @Asheesh see answers in edit

Comment: Thanks for you explaination @Reinderien, it makes sense now. I was wondering if there is a way to not hard code the machines mc001, mc002 in the for loop under the comment # For every equipment instance. And can we loop the code for each day of the schedule (14 months worth of data) to get the required equipments each day of the schedule?

Comment: _there is a way to not hard code the machines mc001, mc002 in the for loop under the comment # For every equipment instance_ - they aren't hard-coded; read it more carefully. That will loop through _all_ machines, where 0 is the previous machine and 1 is the current machine.

Comment: _can we loop the code for each day of the schedule (14 months worth of data) to get the required equipments each day of the schedule?_ - yes; but that's somewhat over-extending this question and you should file a new one, marking this answer accepted if you believe that it answers your question.

Comment: Thanks @Reinderein, this has been very useful, can't thank you more!!  I'll try to do the loop for each day. I'm thinking to loop around the whole code, do you think is a better way to do it rather then looping around the entire part.

Comment: I have not tested for multiple service periods per one machine, but no, do not add an outer loop. Just add more rows for a machine in the first dataframe.

Comment: You may need to change the grouping criteria where it currently assumes unique machine names.

Comment: The first dataframe will no longer have the machine name as a unique index.

Comment: thanks for your answers so far !! I need to find the minimum number of equipment required over each day of the schedule and put the daily minimums into a dataframe for the entire schedule. I can't think of anything other than an outer loop that will iterate over your code each day and write it to a dataframe.  Do you think there's a better way of doing it? I can put a new post if you would like. Thanks again !!! @Reinderien